# display data in json format

Tags: php, json, xml, parsing, response

How to convert data display format?
I have some data in `xml`. I converted those data into `json` format. But i have problem in displaying data.

Here is my `json` formatted data:

```
{
        "status": "1",
        "data": [
            {
                "@attributes": {
                    "song": "Elona",
                    "album": "AL-F-001",
                    "path": "link1",
                    "calen": "278",
                    "dl": "./demo/AL-F-001_Elona.mp3"
                }
            },
            {
                "@attributes": {
                    "song": "Evis",
                    "album": "AL-F-002",
                    "path": "link2",
                    "calen": "279",
                    "dl": "./demo/AL-F-002_Evis.mp3"
                }
            },
            {
                "@attributes": {
                    "song": "Kozeta",
                    "album": "AL-F-003",
                    "path": "link3",
                    "calen": "280",
                    "dl": "./demo/AL-F-003_Kozeta.mp3"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

What i want is like:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "data": [
        {            
            "song": "Elona",
            "album": "AL-F-001",
            "path": "link1",
            "calen": "278",
            "dl": "./demo/AL-F-001_Elona.mp3"
        },
        {
            "song": "Evis",
            "album": "AL-F-002",
            "path": "link2",
            "calen": "279",
            "dl": "./demo/AL-F-002_Evis.mp3"
        },
        {
            "song": "Kozeta",
            "album": "AL-F-003",
            "path": "link3",
            "calen": "280",
            "dl": "./demo/AL-F-003_Kozeta.mp3"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i do that? Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: what language? add approriate tags.

Comment: @Greg language is `php`..

Answer (score 0):

What about iterating over the array and make data[i] = data[i]["@attributes"]